# PHP: Заменить белый фон в PNG картинке на прозрачный

Tags: php, изображения

Пытаюсь сделать прозрачный фон в PNG картинке, но в результате остается белый:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('http://i.imgur.com/iTgGpao.png');

imagealphablending($img, true);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
$white = imagecolorexact($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($img, $white);

imagepng($img, 'result.png');
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если верить [справке](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecolortransparent.php), для создания цвета вместо `imagecolorexact()` необходимо использовать `imagecolorallocate()`

**Upd.** ваш пример у меня заработал после удаления двух этих строк:

```
imagealphablending($img, true);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
```

То есть вот так:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('http://i.imgur.com/iTgGpao.png');

$white = imagecolorexact($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($img, $white);

imagepng($img, 'result.png');
```

Либо с выставлением параметра **saveflag** функции [imagesavealpha()](http://php.net/imageSaveAlpha) равным **false**:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('http://i.imgur.com/iTgGpao.png');

imagealphablending($img, true);
imagesavealpha($img, false);

$white = imagecolorexact($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($img, $white);
```

Comment: Аналогичная проблема с imagecolorallocate()

Comment: тогда другое глупое предположение :) у вас установлена библиотека GD? что выводит `var_dump(gd_info());`?

Comment: Выводит: array(12) {
  'GD Version' =>
  string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)"
  'FreeType Support' =>
  bool(true)
  'FreeType Linkage' =>
  string(13) "with freetype"
  'T1Lib Support' =>
  bool(false)
  'GIF Read Support' =>
  bool(true)
  'GIF Create Support' =>
  bool(true)
  'JPEG Support' =>
  bool(true)
  'PNG Support' =>
  bool(true)
  'WBMP Support' =>
  bool(true)
  'XPM Support' =>
  bool(true)
  'XBM Support' =>
  bool(true)
  'JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support' =>
  bool(false)
}

Comment: у меня ваш пример после удаления манипуляций с альфа каналами

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо :)